# How is the order of initialization and finalization determined?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

I Always thought that the correct order of forms's life cycle is `initialization -> Create -> OnCreate -> OnDestroy -> Destroy -> finalization` which works for following code.

```
Application.Initialize;
Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
Application.CreateForm(TUMain, UMain);
Application.Run;
```

However when i make a little change...

```
Application.Initialize;
Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
Application.CreateForm(TUMain, UMain);
if 1 = 2 then
  Application.Run;
```

then `TUMain` order changes to `initialization -> Create -> OnCreate -> finalization -> OnDestroy -> Destroy`

So I wonder, how is exact order controlled or at least what caused the change in this case?

Comment: Take a look at the debugger. The form is destroyed by the unit finalization of `Vcl.Forms.pas` when it calls `DoneApplication()`. I'd suggest to stay away from unit initialization/finalization. Use Constructors and destructors. Or, if you wish, the `OnCreate` and `OnDestroy` event of visual forms.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you never call `Application.Run` then auto-created forms (or any forms created with `Application.CreateForm`, for that matter) are freed in `FinalizeUnits` rather than when the main form closes.

Ordinarily `Application.Run` assigns `ExitProc` which calls `DoneApplication` - this enumerates windows owned by the applicaton and frees them before `FinalizeUnits` is called.  If `Application.Run` is not called then there is no assigned `ExitProc` and the forms do not get freed until `FinalizeUnits` is called.